# How many computational steps to determine $\pi(x)$ at $x=10^{12}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just like the title says, how many actions are required by a computer (or a person) to determine $\pi(x)$ at $x$ equals $10^{12}$ with the most modern method?

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by "*pi of x*". Perhaps you want to calculate $\pi$ to $x$ decimal places?

Comment: @MikePierce: I'm guessing $\pi(x)$ means the $x$th prime number, or else the number of primes less than or equal to $x$...

Comment: I think the reference is to the number of primes less than (or equal to) $10^{12}$.

Comment: Naively, we could note that modern computers have access to terabytes worth of storage, so we could say that $\pi(\sqrt{x})$ "actions" are required (as an upper bound), if one "action" is to go through 1TB of memory locations for each successively-discovered prime and cross out all the non-primes divisible by it...

Comment: The sieve of eratosthenes takes time $O(n \log \log n)$ multiplications to compute $\pi(n)$.

Comment: That sieve is slow, no?

Comment: @abiessu, is what you are saying is that it would the root of x steps to determine the number of primes below x?

Comment: While sieves can find all the primes up to a given $x$, this is more work than necessary to count those primes.  A search for "prime counting function" may turn up some useful information (in addition to extensive and obsessive narcissistic opining on the problem).

Comment: It is notable that there are many good approximations for $\pi(x)$ at any given value, so that this could significantly quicken the computational effort required

Comment: I am saying that it is a naive approach to the problem that gives a starting point.  Yes, it would take on the order of $\sqrt x$ (or $\ln x$) steps to complete, except that each step is "cross out these many entries in the database".  One failing of this approach is that the space needed to check all the numbers up to $x$ cannot be used for anything else until the process is complete.

Comment: @abiessu So your answer is, yes the root of x, and that would still be an approximation correct? I mean not an exact answer?

Comment: @abiessu Am I to assume by what you are saying that there is no way to build a list without already having it?

Comment: No, you get an exact answer, as a byproduct of having computed every single prime.  And no, the sieve of Eratosthenes does not depend on any knowledge of primes except that you skip $1$ in the process.  The rest is just the fact that you would have to keep the whole 1TB reserved for the duration of the calculation; once completed it could be compressed via normal mechanisms, or counted and discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is
Meissel's formula and its
modern descendents:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

In that article,
they link to this paper:
http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf

In the abstract,
they say that
"We show that it is possible to compute π(x) in 
$O( \frac{x^{2/3}}
{\log^2 x} )
$ time
and 
$O(x^{1/3} \log^3 x \log \log x)
$ space."